# Create new EC2 instance on increase in number of messages in queue

Tags: amazon-ec2, rabbitmq

Is there a way to create new EC2 instances on an increasing number of messages in RabbitMq queue?

Answer (score 0):

Giving for granted that you know how to set up an Auto Scaling Group, you can configure your group to adjust in capacity according to demand, in response to Amazon [CloudWatch](https://aws.amazon.com/cloudwatch/) metrics.

The thing is, **you can store your own metrics in CloudWatch** using the [PutMetricData](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/APIReference/API_PutMetricData.html) function.

So you should:

- somehow send to CloudWatch the number of messages RabbitMq is managing, maybe with a cron script;
- check that CloudWatch is receiving your data;
- create a [Launch Template](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-launch-templates.html) for your scaling EC2 instances;
- create an Auto Scaling Group setting a trigger tied to your new
  CloudWatch metric.

Comment: Thanks, @daniele for a quick reply. let me give a try.

Comment: I am agree to some extent, but you need to setup service discovery mechanism to link both services or you can try official RabbitMQ plugin https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-autocluster or
https://github.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-peer-discovery-aws